# parsing and reading a json array java

Tags: java, arrays, json

have a structure for a contact book:

```
Contact { "Name":{ "First name":"Erm","Last Name": "Smith" }, "Number":67485647 }.
```

I save it as a Json object and than store it in a file with createContact().

```
public synchronized void createContact (String fname, String lname,String typeof, int number) throws FileNotFoundException 
{   
    JsonObjectBuilder contactBuilder = Json.createObjectBuilder();
    JsonObjectBuilder nameBuilder = Json.createObjectBuilder();
    JsonArrayBuilder  contactArrayBuilder= Json.createArrayBuilder();

    nameBuilder.add("First Name",fname);
    nameBuilder.add("Last Name",lname);
    contactBuilder.add("Name", nameBuilder);
    contactBuilder.add("Type", typeof);
    contactBuilder.add("number", number);

    JsonObject contact = contactBuilder.build();
    contactArrayBuilder.add(contact);
    JsonArray contactArray=contactArrayBuilder.build();

    //write to file
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    JsonWriter fileWriter = Json.createWriter(os);
    fileWriter.writeArray(contactArray);
    fileWriter.close();
}
```

I read the file with:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(filename);
JsonReader fileReader = Json.createReader(is);
JsonArray contactObj = (JsonArray) Json.createParserFactory(fileReader.readObject());
JsonArrayBuilder contactArrayBuilder= Json.createArrayBuilder();
```

This is when I get the error

```
javax.json.JsonException: Cannot read JSON object, found JSON array
at org.glassfish.json.JsonReaderImpl.readObject(JsonReaderImpl.java:105)
```

I am using javax.json

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are storing a JsonArray in that file, and then trying to read that JsonArray as a JsonObject. What you can do to get your code to work is remove these lines:

```
JsonArray contactObj = (JsonArray) Json.createParserFactory(fileReader.readArray());
JsonArrayBuilder contactArrayBuilder= Json.createArrayBuilder();
```

and replace them with something like this:

```
JsonArray array = fileReader.readArray();
```

In the end, reading the file will look like this:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(filename);
JsonReader fileReader = Json.createReader(is);
JsonArray array = fileReader.readArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
JsonArray contactObj = (JsonArray) Json.createParserFactory(fileReader.readObject());
```

to this

```
JsonArray contactObj = (JsonArray) Json.createParserFactory(fileReader.readArray());
```

as you are expecting an array but reading the object you are getting this error.

Comment: If I do it like you suggest I get an error because createParserFactory does not take an array argument. If I do it like this:                                                                    JsonArray contactObj = (JsonArray) Json.createParser((Reader) fileReader.readArray());                                                                                This dos not give an error, but is it a correct way to do it?

Comment: No I get the same error if I do that in the above comment

Comment: You can just do `JsonArray contactObj = fileReader.readArray();` and it should work I think